# C# .Is there a .NET class for custom thread pools

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have been trying to find a simple custom thread pool for a while, and couldn't find one, so wrote a quick poor man's thread pool.

**Questions**:

1. Is there any .NET class that can do this already? (couldn't find it after numerous attempts to find one, only custom implementations on blog posts that were a lot more complex than this!).
2. Better to consume threads with polling or kicking off actions on thread pool when and as tasks come in? <1k tasks / day. This will be running as AspNetCore site on Kestrel

## Code

```
public class WorkerQueue : IWorkerQueue
{
    private readonly Queue<WorkItem> _items = new Queue<WorkItem>();

    private int _max = 2; // Would be configurable
    private int _running;
    private Stopwatch _stopwatch;

    public WorkerQueue()
    {
        _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        _stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public void Add(WorkItem workItem)
    {
        lock (_items)
        {
            if (_running >= _max)
            {
                Log($"Queuing Item {workItem.Name} - _running >= _max");
                _items.Enqueue(workItem);
                return;
            }

            _running++;

            Log($"Running Item {workItem.Name} - _running = {_running}");
            var task = Task.Run(workItem.Action);

            task.ContinueWith(t => OnActionCompleted(workItem.Name));
        }
    }

    private void Log(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} @ {_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms : {msg}");
    }

    private void OnActionCompleted(string obj)
    {
        Log($"OnActionCompleted {obj}");
        WorkItem item = null;

        lock (_items)
        {
            if (_items.Count > 0)
                item = _items.Dequeue();
            else
                _running--;
        }

        if (item != null)
        {
            // Potential Stack Overflow if big queue builds up?
            // Probably should be a while loop rather than recursion?
            Log($"Running Next Item {item.Name}");
            item.Action();
            OnActionCompleted(item.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Log($"Sleeping. _running = {_running}");
        }
    }
}
```

And a test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        Console.SetOut(new StringWriter(sb));

        var resetEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim();

        AddItem("A", 100);
        AddItem("B", 250);
        AddItem("C", 100);
        AddItem("D", 100);
        AddItem("E", 100);
        AddItem("G", 100, () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            resetEvent.Set();
        });

        resetEvent.Wait(2500);

        Assert.True(resetEvent.IsSet);

        _output.WriteLine("");
        _output.WriteLine("------------------ Test Finished ------------------");
        _output.WriteLine("------------------  Console Out  ------------------");
        _output.WriteLine("");
        _output.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
```

And get this output which is correct (or correct enough)

```
Thread 14 @ 8ms : Running Item A - _running = 1
Thread 14 @ 8ms : Running Item B - _running = 2
Thread 14 @ 8ms : Queuing Item C - _running >= _max
Thread 14 @ 8ms : Queuing Item D - _running >= _max
Thread 14 @ 8ms : Queuing Item E - _running >= _max
Thread 14 @ 8ms : Queuing Item G - _running >= _max
Thread 21 @ 110ms : OnActionCompleted A
Thread 21 @ 110ms : Running Next Item C
Thread 21 @ 211ms : OnActionCompleted C
Thread 21 @ 211ms : Running Next Item D
Thread 20 @ 260ms : OnActionCompleted B
Thread 20 @ 260ms : Running Next Item E
Thread 21 @ 311ms : OnActionCompleted D
Thread 21 @ 311ms : Running Next Item G
Thread 20 @ 360ms : OnActionCompleted E
Thread 20 @ 360ms : Sleeping. _running = 1
Thread 21 @ 662ms : OnActionCompleted G
Thread 21 @ 662ms : Sleeping. _running = 0
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com site

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy changed the question to ask if there is already something available in the ,NET framework already

Comment: Task is the new thread in .NETCore and it is managed via a thread pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the [parallel extensions extras project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/parallel-programming-extensions-extras-cs/), it has several task schedulers.  Specifically, `WorkStealingTaskScheduler`.

I remember having tested it, and nothing in the managed world compares to .NET's own thread pool, at least without unsafe code.  .NET's stock thread pool has a lot of optimizations under the hood, one I remember clearly is spinning aggressively for work items after processing one work item before waiting.

On the bright side, you can get very close to it, but emulating what the `ThreadPool` does is quite a feat.  That is, if you want to do so.  One of the reasons I'd like **not** to use the default thread pool is due to its policy about creating threads slowly after min. threads, but simply increasing min. threads is usually good enough.

The thing is, unless you're using TPL **and** you can provide your own task scheduler, typically nothing else, especially legacy code, is going to pick up your custom thread pool as there is no stock thread pool interface.  Unfortunately, the fact that `ThreadPool` is a static class further discourages the usage of other thread pools.

Comment: I am not looking for overriding the default Threadpool, but a separate threadpool, that I can que work to, and specify how many can run at one time.

Comment: I understand that, did you read my first paragraph?  The `WorkStealingTaskScheduler` is probably the closest thing to a thread pool implementation in managed code by Microsoft itself.  But see `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` in the same project.